# cordova file plugin applicationDirectory equivalent for windows 8 app

Tags: windows, file, cordova, filesystems

I am using Cordova and File plugin to list contents under assets directory in www. 
On iOS i'm getting the file entry passing cordova.file.applicationDirectory to window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL and everything is working as expected.

```
var url = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + '/www/assets/';

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
    url, 
    onSuccess, 
    onFail
);
```

When I switch to windows app environment cordova.file.applicationDirectory is undefined. I tried using Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation or Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder with no luck.
 
What is the correct way to resolve local file system url for windows?

Comment: Have you solved the issue finally?

Comment: @Nicola Gnecchi Did you get any solution ?