# What path is in Windows Phone for files?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, path, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

I'm using a cordova to build an app on Windows Phone and I need to know what is a path(directory) for saving files into internal memory, like we have in Windows (C://ProgramFiles/..).
For example Android have file://(...) or cdvfile:///(...).

Someone maybe know how to check it or know it?

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score -1):

Just follow cordova file plugin [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#windows-file-system-layout)

Comment: I saw it earlier, but it isn't for Windows OS (I mean destop OS) ?

Comment: Ok, if you want to know the path for save files, make a `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory)` and print fileEntry result

Comment: Maybe you know answer on this question?  [QuestionOnStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45297286/invalid-modification-err-windows-phone?noredirect=1#comment77574203_45297286) @Djiggy

Comment: And for this question have you your response ?

Comment: I received a error "TypeError: Unable to get property 'applicationDirectory' of undefined or null reference", I looked a little bit about it and found this topic about [problemWithAppDir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237813/cordova-file-plugin-applicationdirectory-equivalent-for-windows-8-app)

Comment: Can you check  steps in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515414/cordova-file-all-directories-are-null)

Comment: I checked 3/4 points, but I have problem with last one, could you tell which part of code I should set in timeout method?